# Does United Nations Laissez-Passer (UNLP) holder needs visa for Greece

Tags: visas, greece

I am a citizen of Eritrea and I work for the United Nations and have UN blue passport - UNLP, do I need an entrance visa to visit Greece as a tourist?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://cibtvisas.com/forms?formname=portalforms/UNDP/Introduction%20-%20Guide-to-the-Issuance-of-UN-Travel-Documents.pdf Laissez-Passers are issued for use only on official travel during a period of employment. (K 36 Validity).

Timatic says you need a visa for Greece unless you are traveling on duty for a maximum stay of 90 days. https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b

Comment: While it is correct that the UNLP is issued for official travel, some countries grant a visa exemption to holders of the UNLP who are traveling for personal reasons (at least South Africa did so in 2016; I'm not sure about the current state of affairs).  I am not surprised that Greece is not among them; I suspect that few if any of the richer countries would be.